# Populating the empty xy fields in point layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have a number of points that form a line, with xyz values for each 100th meter, aka Chainage Number (this is a railway tunnel, chainage number 2900 = 2900 meters from a train station).

But I want xyz values for every meter and have therefore (in excel) added 99 rows below each 100th Chainage Number, and linearly calculated the z values in the empty rows  based on the z values for every 100th meter. In the added table image the Chainage Numbers are in field called "Inbound_Ch", not sure why the xy values are "1" in what I call empty rows.

How can I calculate the xy values in the empty rows?
I use arcgis 10.3.

[image: attribute table of points with empty xy rows]
[image: the points for each 100th meter with accompanying line, linear straight distance between each 100 meter point]

Comment: right click on the name of column and chose calculate geometry, than for each coordinate chose the right geometry to calculate

Comment: I did do that and ended up either with Null values or just 1 (somehow), like in the table image here.

Comment: be sure about the dataframe coordinate system and shapefile coordinate system. They should be in the same coordinate system. 
Or create a new field (type Double) than apply calculate geometry. 
Try the tool "add geometry attribute"  under "Data management/ Feature / Add geometry attribute".

Comment: one of above option should work correctly if you have correct coordinate system.

Comment: You're using Z for something normally stored in M (the measure).  Have you read anything about [linear referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm)?

Comment: how did you "add the rows" ? This is not clear from your text.

Comment: @Florjan I used the Repair Geometry tool and seems like 18324 of my 18510 rows have null geometry, these 18324 are the added rows inbetween the rows with xyz.

Comment: @radouxju I used excel to add the rows, and to calculate the z values in the added rows

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I don't know what you mean, I haven't used linear referencing before, but I am reading into it. The values in the Z field is height above sea level in meters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following solution for my own problem:

Because all my points were along a line and (were supposed to be) exactly 1 meter apart from each other, I used the Construct Points function in Edit mode so I could get the xy coordinates from the line it was based on. What also made this easier was that the points could easily be assigned a number (the chainage number) in a new field and then joined with the original table that had the z coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Adding rows in excel does not create a geometry.

In your case one solution could be to create your X and Y coordiantes in excel (you can interpolate between 2 points spaced by 100m, e.g. X_1924 = X_1900 + 0.24* (X_2000 - X1900) ) then add those point using "add XY table". The same linear interpolation can be applied on Y and Z.

Comment: Thanks @radouxju this is a good solution, but because the line was not straight all the way it was a bit to complicated for me to calculate this way. It was quite curvy and swinging a bit back and forth, which I forgot to specify in my question. I did however find another solution that I have posted as an additional answer here.